# Do the projects created by archetype plugins use old versions of dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, junit

I am running

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

and then choose `maven-archetype-quickstart`  archetype plugin. Then it creates a maven project with a pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>ocean.earth</groupId>
  <artifactId>mytest</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>mytest</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I find the version of JUnit is 3.8.1, surprisingly old, given that the latest version of JUnit is already 5.0.1, and I am using the latest version of Maven 3.5.2.

I was wondering whether it is common that the projects created by archetype plugins use old versions of dependencies?

How shall I make the plugins create projects using newer versions of dependencies?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to this question ...

> Do the projects created by archetype plugins use old versions of dependencies?

... is: the `<dependencies/>` block in the `pom.xml` produced by `maven-archetype-quickstart` is a snapshot of the current versions of those dependencies *as they were* when the archetype artifact was created.

For background: an archetype is (more or less) an archive which contains some static content along with a mechanism for substituting user supplied values for tokens within that content.

The `maven-archetype-quickstart` includes some static content (a `pom.xml`) and supports token substitution allowing you to supply your own values for `groupId`, `artifactId`, `projectVersion` etc.

So, when you create a project from this archetype the static `pom.xml` is updated with your supplied values and the updated version is the POM for your newly created project.

The `pom.xml` within the archetype also contains `<dependencies/>` such as:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

The `<dependencies/>` block is entirely static and cannot be updated by anything you supply when running the archetype command so the `junit` dependency will always remain `3.8.1`. The choice of `3.8.1` is a result of *when* the latest version of the `maven-archetype-quickstart` artifact was created: **April, 2010**.

So, it's fair to say that the `maven-archetype-quickstart` artifact is - with respect to the `<dependencies/>` block - out of date. The other things which the archetype does (creating a `pom.xml` with your `groupId`, `artifactId` etc and creating the standard Maven project structure) remain valid.

In answer to this:

> How shall I make the plugins create projects using newer versions of dependencies

You could ...

- Update the versions produced by the `maven-archetype-quickstart`
- Create your own archetype with later versions than those provided by `maven-archetype-quickstart`
- Create your own `pom.xml` without using the archetype

Comment: Thanks. I modified the created pom.xml to update the version of junit. But compiling will not pass, because the created test java file still uses the old version of  junit, which is no  longer supported by the recent versions of junit. I don't know how to create my own archetype yet. Is there any way to create a project template using the recent versions of Junit?

Comment: Regardless of _how_ you create a project (your own archetype, a provided archetype, manually) you'll need your classes to be compatible with your dependencies so you'll need to update your test classes to use the JUnit 5.x constructs. Re this: "Is there any way to create a project template using the recent versions of Junit" ...  either create the project by hand or else update the dependencies provided by the out of date `maven-archetype-quickstart`.